# What is the difference between Gradle's "maven" and "maven-publish" plugins?

Tags: java, gradle

I am confused when and why I should choose one of them. Most of functions are common.

Answer (score 24):

Both `maven` and `maven-publish` are Gradle plugins for publishing an artifact in a Maven compatible format, that is most often a `pom.xml` and associated `jar` file.

The former is now considered deprecated and `maven-publish` should be used instead, as of Gradle `4.8`. Features like signing of artifacts and improved DSL for pom file manipulation have [recently been added](https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/release-notes.html) to `maven-publish` making it the preferred choice from now on.

Comment: I do think at least one goal of the maven plugin is to _convert_ the project from gradle to maven. Which is different from publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Maven-publish is for publish artifacts to Maven repository, from documentation

> The Maven Publish Plugin provides the ability to publish build
>   artifacts to an Apache Maven repository. A module published to a Maven repository can be consumed by Maven

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html

And when these artifacts are published you can use them with Maven or Gradle.